# Daily mean of subset of columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe (with datetime index):

```
                col_a   col_b   col_c   col_d   col_e   col_f   col_g   col_h   fid
7/20/2017 10:00  0      18  45  17  19  2.777778    180 0.92    999000
7/20/2017 11:00 0.03    18  45  17  19  2.2222224   180 0.93    999000
7/20/2017 12:00 0.03    18  45  17  19  2.2222224   180 0.95    999000
7/20/2017 13:00 0.03    17  45  17  19  2.2222224   180 0.95    999000
7/20/2017 14:00 0.04    17  45  17  19  1.6666668   180 0.97    999000
7/20/2017 15:00 0.03    17  45  17  19  1.6666668   180 0.97    999000
7/20/2017 16:00 0.02    17  45  17  19  1.6666668   157.5   0.97    999000
7/20/2017 17:00 0.01    17  45  17  19  1.6666668   135 0.97    999000
7/20/2017 18:00 0.01    17  45  17  19  1.6666668   157.5   0.97    999000
7/20/2017 19:00 0.02    17  45  17  19  1.6666668   157.5   1   999000
7/20/2017 20:00 0.01    17  45  17  19  2.2222224   135 1   999000
7/20/2017 21:00 0.01    18  45  17  19  2.2222224   135 1   999000
7/20/2017 22:00 0.01    18  45  17  19  2.777778    157.5   0.98    999000
7/20/2017 23:00 0.03    19  45  17  19  2.777778    157.5   0.96    999000
7/21/2017 0:00  0.04    19  45  16  21  3.0555558   157.5   0.92    999000
7/21/2017 1:00  0.05    20  45  16  21  3.8888892   157.5   0.88    999000
7/21/2017 2:00  0.03    21  45  16  21  3.8888892   157.5   0.83    999000
7/21/2017 3:00  0.02    21  45  16  21  3.8888892   157.5   0.8 999000
7/21/2017 4:00  0.03    21  45  16  21  4.4444448   157.5   0.78    999000
7/21/2017 5:00  0.03    21  45  16  21  4.4444448   157.5   0.79    999000
7/21/2017 6:00  0.02    21  45  16  21  3.8888892   157.5   0.83    999000
7/21/2017 7:00  0.03    20  45  16  21  3.6111114   135 0.86    999000
7/21/2017 8:00  0.04    19  45  16  21  3.0555558   157.5   0.91    999000
7/21/2017 9:00  0.03    18  45  16  21  2.777778    157.5   0.92    999000
7/21/2017 10:00 0.03    18  45  16  21  2.777778    157.5   0.92    999000
7/21/2017 11:00 0.03    18  45  16  21  2.777778    157.5   0.92    999000
7/21/2017 12:00 0.02    17  45  16  21  2.777778    135 0.94    999000
7/21/2017 13:00 0.03    17  45  16  21  2.777778    135 0.95    999000
7/21/2017 14:00 0.03    17  45  16  21  2.777778    135 0.98    999000
7/21/2017 15:00 0.03    17  45  16  21  2.777778    157.5   0.97    999000
7/21/2017 16:00 0.04    17  45  16  21  2.777778    135 0.97    999000
7/21/2017 17:00 0.04    17  45  16  21  2.777778    135 0.98    999000
7/21/2017 18:00 0.04    17  45  16  21  2.777778    135 1   999000
7/21/2017 19:00 0.03    16  45  16  21  2.777778    135 1   999000
7/21/2017 20:00 0.03    17  45  16  21  3.0555558   135 1   999000
7/21/2017 21:00 0.03    17  45  16  21  3.0555558   135 1   999000
7/21/2017 22:00 0.03    17  45  16  21  3.0555558   135 0.99    999000
7/21/2017 23:00 0.03    17  45  16  21  3.0555558   157.5   0.97    999000
```

I want to compute daily means for col_a, col_b... col_h. The fid column seems to contain numbers but they are actually stored as strings. For that column I just want the unique string for each day. However, when I do this:

```
df.resample('D').mean()
```

The `fid` column disappers from the final output. How do I get it in the final output?

Comment: `lambda` and `if esle `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need resample some values differently (like column `fid` because text column) is possible use [`Resampler.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) by `dict`, which can be dynamically created.

Last add [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) for get same order of columns as in input `df`.

```
#all columns without `fid` are aggregate by mean
d = {x:'mean' for x in df.columns.difference(['fid'])}
#added new item to dict - column fid is aggregate by first
d['fid'] = 'first'
print (d)
{'col_e': 'mean', 'col_c': 'mean', 'col_b': 'mean', 'col_f': 'mean', 
'col_a': 'mean', 'col_d': 'mean', 'fid': 'first', 'col_h': 'mean', 'col_g': 'mean'}


df1 = df.resample('D').agg(d).reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df1)
               col_a      col_b  col_c  col_d  col_e     col_f       col_g  \
2017-07-20  0.020000  17.500000     45     17     19  2.103175  162.321429   
2017-07-21  0.031667  18.333333     45     16     21  3.206019  147.187500   

               col_h     fid  
2017-07-20  0.967143  999000  
2017-07-21  0.921250  999000
```

If resample by [`Resampler.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.mean.html) only, all non numeric columns are exluded ([similar as `aggregation`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns)):

```
df1 = df.resample('D').mean()
print (df1)
               col_a      col_b  col_c  col_d  col_e     col_f       col_g  \
2017-07-20  0.020000  17.500000   45.0   17.0   19.0  2.103175  162.321429   
2017-07-21  0.031667  18.333333   45.0   16.0   21.0  3.206019  147.187500   

               col_h  
2017-07-20  0.967143  
2017-07-21  0.921250
```

Another solution is use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) if data in `fid` are same per day:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['fid', pd.Grouper(freq='D')])
        .mean()
        .reset_index()
        .reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df1)
      col_a      col_b  col_c  col_d  col_e     col_f       col_g     col_h  \
0  0.020000  17.500000   45.0   17.0   19.0  2.103175  162.321429  0.967143   
1  0.031667  18.333333   45.0   16.0   21.0  3.206019  147.187500  0.921250   

      fid  
0  999000  
1  999000
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael, I want to retain it as string since it could potentially be alphanumeric down the road.

Comment: @user308827 in that case, you can create a new column with the new type

Comment: Ok, but if need aggreagate data - so e.g. from 4 rows create 1, how is desired output from `fid`? First value?

Comment: so fid is guaranteed to have the same value for the entire day, so I just need unique

Comment: @Jakub - if column not numeric, it is automatically removed.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you @jezrael. sorry for the misinformation

Comment: thanks @jezrael, what does `d['fid'] = 'first'` mean?

Comment: thanks @jezrael, is it possible to get the datetime index back in your second soln?

Comment: sorry, only omit `.reset_index()`

Comment: Yes, I realised last it is possible use `Grouper`, but sometimes it is not possible and is necessary only `agg`. Good luck and thank you for accepting!